# Api call inside for loop in node js is not behaving synchronously even with bluebird, sync etc

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, promise, bluebird

I writing a function that would use an array called "courses" and filter elements from this array based on the response from an api call. I want the for loop in the array to behave synchronously. Thus, I have used libraries like deasync, bluebird and sync in hopes of doing so. However, the call to the api function  (i.e. customauth.callAPI inside the for loop) is happening asynchronously, in this case after the whole for loop has executed.
Kindly look at my code and tell me where I am going wrong. I have extracts from two files dashboard.js (which has a get route "getDashboard") and a file that called customauth.js which is a helper to the api.

```
  //dashboard.js     
    const customauth= require('./customauth');
    var bluebird = require('bluebird');

     router.get('/getDashboard', (req, res) => {
            token = req.headers['authorization'];
            let callRoles = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
            customauth.callAPI(token, 'viewAllCourseInfo', { }, function(err, response, body) {
              if (!err){
                var parsed = JSON.parse(body);
                resolve(parsed);
              }else{
                reject(false);
              }
            });
          });


          callRoles.then(function(courses){
            var getCoursesWithManager = bluebird.coroutine(function* (courses) {
              var coursesWithManager = [];

              for (var i = 0; i < courses.dataSet.length; i++) {
                var params = new Array();
                params["cid"] = courses.dataSet[i].uniqueid;
                console.log(courses.dataSet[i]);
                //This is the api call happening at the very end, but I need 
                //this synchronously
                customauth.callAPI(token, 'viewUserRole', params, function(err, 
                response, body) {
                  var parsed = JSON.parse(body);
                  if( parsed.role.indexOf("managers") > -1) {
                    coursesWithManager.push(courses.dataSet[i]);
                 }
                });
              }

              res.json({success: true, data: coursesWithManager});
            });

            getCoursesWithManager(courses);


          });
        });


//customauth.js
 var request = require('request');
 var host = 'HOST_URL';


function callAPI(accessToken, method, parameters, callback){
        var url = host+method+'?accessToken='+accessToken;
        for (var para in parameters) {
            url+='&'+para+'='+parameters[para];
        }

        options = {
            url: url
        };
request(options, callback);
}
```

Comment: Unless you're stuck on this version, I'd use a more recent version of node and declare callAPI as an async function, then you can do a 'wait' for it inside of the callRoles.then() callback. You could also wrap that routine in a Promise since you're importing bluebird already; just do import Promise from 'bluebird' and do return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { ... logic });

Comment: You don't know what you're asking for by saying you want this done synchronously within Node.js.  Be VERY careful doing this.  Anything "synchronous" should mostly be done in the bootstrapping of some node application.  Please research the implications behind using synchronous calls in node, before you go off and use them.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use bluebird but if you want to run promises synchronously (if I understand what you mean) you can use the async/await keyword and a function that generates a closure. For example:

```
async function sequentialPromises(arr) {
    return arr.reduce((promise, item, index) => {
        return promise.then(() => {
            return someClosure(item).then(() => console.log('something')
        })
    }, Promise.resolve())
}
```

Where you wrap your `callAPI` in some closure (or better yet rewrite with closures in mind):

```
function someClosure(course) {
  var params = new Array();
  params["cid"] = courses.dataSet[i].uniqueid;

  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    customauth.callAPI(token, 'viewUserRole', params, function(err, response, body) {
        resolve(err, response, body)
    });
  })
}
```

So now instead of the `console.log('something')` you can now replace it with the code you actually wanted to execute:

```
var parsed = JSON.parse(body);
if( parsed.role.indexOf("managers") > -1) {
    coursesWithManager.push(courses.dataSet[i]);
}
```

Now ditch the for-loop in callRoles and instead use `await sequentialPromises(courses)`:

```
callRoles.then(function (courses) {
  var getCoursesWithManager = bluebird.coroutine(function* (courses) {
    var coursesWithManager = [];
    await sequentialPromises(courses)
    res.json({success: true, data: coursesWithManager});
  })
})
```

There are some scope inconsistencies in these examples but as with how your code is formatted I think you can easily solve this.